# How to capture Protractor error messages shown in Terminal

Tags: javascript, protractor

I run my Protractor tests on my application and there are about 6 E2E tests. If any error happens during these, they are shown in the terminal. For eg - (1) Expected 'abc' to be 'def' or (2) Element #id123 is not clickable at point 15,10.

Is there any way to capture these errors in XML format or any other form in the system, instead of just displaying them onto the terminal. Maybe using some plugins or something? Any help will be thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are ways to store those errors. You can use one of many available reporters. For example if you want to store XML files you can use `jasmine-reporters`: https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters.
Or if you prefer html then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter. There are plenty of different reporters, you just have to google.

When setting up you reporter you have to assign it in your config file.

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: '..',
        consolidateAll: false
     });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
}
```

If you are using `node.js` then you have to import the actual reporters:

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
```

I'd recommend you read more about it here: https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

Answer (score 0):

There is `jasmine-spec-reporter` if you want the output to be in a nice-formatted text way. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter). I use it in my Protractor tests.

To use it in your protractor tests, you need to add this to your configuration file.

```
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config={
 //your configuration here

 onPrepare:function(){
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec:{
          displayStacktrace:true
      },
      summary:{
          displayDuration:false
      }

  }));
};
```

To have this output in a text file I simply add a text file in my protractor tests like

```
     protractor myconf.js  >text_file.txt
```

and it gives me a formatted output. You can also find a demo example in my repository [here](https://github.com/zac11/jasmine_spec_reporter).